# I am trying to pass a context to an Intent to start an Activity in a Kotlin RecyclerView.Holder class but does not recognize the context

Tags: android, kotlin, android-intent, android-recyclerview

```
class MyYugioHolder(view: View):RecyclerView.ViewHolder(view)  {
  private val binding = ItemYugioSavedBinding.bind(view)

  fun bind(yugio: YugioEntity){
    with(binding){
        tvIndex.text = formatNumberTo3Digits(yugio.idb.toInt())
        tvName.text = yugio.name
        Glide
            .with(itemView)
            .load(yugio.image)
            .into(binding.ivYugioLogoCard)

        gosee.setOnClickListener{
            startActivity(Intent(getContext(), MainActivity::class.java))   //!!!!PROBLEM!!!

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify where do you keep this code: inside Activity? 

Just trying to understand - on what object do you call startActivity? Activity.startActivity?

Comment: What do you mean by "does not recognize the Context"? Is this a compiler error? What is the error?

Comment: I'm calling startActivity on a RecyclerView.ViewHolder class

Comment: The error appears in getContext() because it doesn't recognize getContext () as a contexto parameter